# Multiple sensors using robot localization

Tags: navigation, ekf, ros-kinetic, robot-localization, ekf-localization-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, currently i'm using an EKF from the robot localization package to generate the odom->base_link transformation. For this, i'm using three sources: wheels velocities, laser and visual. Since visual and laser approaches rely heavily on features my approach was to derive instantaneous velocities from two consecutive measurements in time (yea i know they can be noisy).

In this EKF i'm only using velocities so i don't have any reference for position, thus it seems like that my filter covariances for a two d mode starts to grow slowly for position (velocities are fine).

Besides all this, i never have jumps or nothing on my global EKF which takes this velocities from the first ekf and fuse them with a global estimator such as AMCL.

My questions are:

- can the parameter dynamic process covariance help me in this case? Or
- since i'm not relying on the state prediction (not feeding any dynamics to the my prediction stage) is generating this behaviors?
- Or is just some issue with the integration from velocities to position?

I'm still very new on using and tuning Kalman Filters ;)

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324179/multiple-sensors-using-robot-localization/) by [tiagojdias](https://answers.ros.org/users/41878/tiagojdias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-05-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-06-06**:
I'm not clear what the actual issue is. Are you *trying* to get the state estimate to jump/correct when you fuse it with AMCL data?

In any case, I can't comment at all unless you provide your full EKF configurations, as well as a sample sensor message for each sensor input.

I will say that you should not be fusing the output of one EKF into the second. Just fuse the same input sources in both.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2019-08-22**:
Any update on this? If not, may I close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can close the issue.

I was able to solve the problem after some tune on each sensor covariance.

---

Originally posted by [tiagojdias](https://answers.ros.org/users/41878/tiagojdias/) with karma: 16 on 2019-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0